# kendoui file upload - unable to run parallel ajax request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, user-interface, kendo-ui

I am developing dropbox similar application where user can upload single or multiple files via kendo ui file upload control in ASP.NET MVC.

Issue i am getting is during file upload ..say (2MB file) all other ajax requests are shown in pending state, and once the upload is complete...all the pending requests are executed sequenctially..

Please help me resolving this issue. Unable to find any help on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run your case in production or you are in debugging mode? If in development mode(debugging) try to use release (production) mode and see if there is any change.